# Heating part baked baguettes in lid-covered pyrex

Tags: baking, bread, oven, heat

#### Short question (TL;DR)

Is it possible to heat part baked baguettes (or part baked bread in general) in the oven, but keeping it inside a pyrex container with a lid? If yes, is there any change in baking time? (without the lid it would be 8-10 minutes) Would the baguette taste differently or would it be less crispy if baked like this?

I provide details and also motivation below (just to anticipate questions like "why don't you bake it normally?").

#### Details and motivation

Because of hygienic and health reasons I would prefer to put only containers with a lid in the oven, as the previous flatmates misused it and now even after professional cleaning there are still traces of potentially toxic black dust and I don't want it to fly over my food when heating it.

But regarding part baked baguettes, there is no information on the web about whether it is possible to bake them in a lid-covered pyrex container. I also looked for more general information about baking bread in pyrex, but the existing recipes usually say to use a lid for some time and then to remove the lid and put back bread in the oven for some other time, which would not work for me.

#### What a part baked baguette is

@Max A *part baked* baguette, also known as *bake-at-home* baguette, is a baguette which is already partially baked but still needs further 8-10 minutes baking at home in order to taste like freshly-baked bread. It is usually very long-lasting if its package is not opened (it may last for months) and it does not need to be refrigerated.

[This](https://groceries.morrisons.com/productImages/113/113364011_0_640x640.jpg?identifier=4cfb9f4cd3f05e064aabae460d8a7283) is an example of part baked baguettes.

Comment: what's a baked baguette ?

Comment: @Max A _part baked_ baguette, also known as _bake-at-home_ baguette, is a baguette which is already partially baked but still needs further 8-10 minutes baking at home in order to taste like freshly-baked bread. It is usually very long-lasting if its package is not opened, it may last for months and it does not need to be refrigerated.

Comment: I will also add the above description in the question.

Comment: I'd use aluminum foil instead of a lid, so that the humidity escape.

Comment: Many thanks @Max , do you think humidity would create problems in a big pyrex container? Or perhaps you mean it would just prevent it from drying correctly and being crispy?

Comment: yep, it might create a more humid bread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect the cooking time to increase significantly, and the texture to be very different (probably not very baguette-like. To mitigate this, you could preheat the pyrex container (put it in the cold oven, turn the oven on, and leave a few minutes after the oven claims to have heated up). I would also look for a way to ventilate the lid, like a wooden spoon sticking out.